# Change title font size in Plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, plotly

I'm trying to update the title font size on my plot using the `Plotly` library, but it doesn't works. This is how I defined my layout:

```
y_layout = {
        'title': 'y / y_hat comparison',
        'shapes': y_shapes,
        'title_font_size': 6,
    }
y_df.iplot(kind='scatter', layout=y_layout)
```

It correctly set the the title and the shapes, but not the font size.

Comment: try to use  style={} see this https://dash.plotly.com/layout

Comment: @abdulraman that's only going to work for a plotly dash app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can set the title font size using a dictionary:

```
y_layout = {
        'title': 'y / y_hat comparison',
        'shapes': y_shapes,
        'font': {'size': 6},
    }
```